# Value at pointer only getting updated if used

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

just noticed some weird behavior, can anyone explain and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I want to implement a Hashset using an array of linked list pointers using C, however, when I add my linked list node, the data value only gets updated if I print it out first.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define print(ref) printf(#ref" = %d\n",ref);
#define HASH_MODULE 13

typedef struct listNode{
    int data;
    struct listNode*next;
}listNode;

void addToSet(int,listNode**);
int hashCode(int);


int main(){
    listNode*linkedListHashset[HASH_MODULE];

    addToSet(10,linkedListHashset);
    print(linkedListHashset[10]->data);

    return 0;
}

void addToSet(int value, listNode**set){
    int bucket = hashCode(value);
    print(bucket);
    listNode newNode = {value};
    newNode.next = set[bucket];
    set[bucket] = &newNode;
    //print(set[bucket]->data);
}

int hashCode(int value){
    return value%HASH_MODULE;
}
```

You can see there's a commented out line, if I compile it like this, the value won't get stored, giving this output (which is not what I would expect):

```
bucket = 10
linkedListHashset[10]->data = 0
```

However, when I include the commented out line here's the output, it does reflect the desired update, here the data at the pointer behaves as I expected:

```
bucket = 10
set[bucket]->data = 10
linkedListHashset[10]->data = 10
```

I'm thinking this might be a compiler artifact or something, I compile by doing:

```
$gcc -Wall -Werror -O -o  source.c
```

Therefore no warnings, everything seems in order. What do you think? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addToSet`, you're declaring `newNode` on the stack, then storing its address in `set[bucket]` and returning. It then becomes a dangling pointer, which leads to undefined behavior when you dereference it in `main`.

Comment: So should I declare a node outside and pass it into the function to prevent undefined behavior?, mmm I guess implementing this in C is harder than I expected..

Comment: While that would fix this problem, it doesn't seem like the right approach here. Instead, try allocating it on the heap with `malloc`.

Comment: Will try that, guess those C++ abstractions have some use after all... but I like to suffer so i will keep doing it in C!!! Thank you very very much.

Comment: All working now using malloc, thank you, I usually don't call it because I want to torture myself using only stdio.h and malloc is on stdlib.h , oh well, is working now, thank you!